# Upper bound for a multivariate continuous random variable

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, information-theory, entropy

I am stuck on this problem:

> Let $X$ be a $\mathbb{R}^n$-valued random variable with zero mean and
>   covariance matrix $\Sigma$. Show that
>
> > $h(X) \le \frac{1}{2}log(2 \pi e)^{n} |\Sigma|$
>
> with equality iff $X$ is multivariate normal.

I believe that, treating the variable as $n$ $\mathbb{R}$-valued random variables,

> $h(X) \le \sum\limits_{i=1}^n h(X_i)$, with equality iff the $X_i$'s are pairwise independent.

However I need some help understanding the meaning of the problem, and where the normal distribution is introduced.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am not an expert on this but you're probably looking at generalizing this to the multivariate case: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Maximum_entropy

Comment: This is proved in Cover &Thomas textbook (Theorem 8.6.5)